# How to get Top Offset of newly injected markup

Tags: jquery, scroll

I've to scroll to the elements location, `scrollTop` It works fine for the elements which are present on the page.

But the same thing when I tried with the injected code its not working. It throws an error saying "**Cannot read property 'top' of null**"

Do I need to delegate to get offset? I know to bind any event I've to. If so then how to do. I'm not getting any solution on the net.

**Edit 1 ::  Adding Code**

```
var element = $('#teacher-recipe-form').find('.clsError').not('label, hidden').first();
if( element.is('input:hidden') ) {
    element = element.parent();
}
var top = element.offset().top - 5;
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: top
}, 500, function(){
    if( element.is('input') || element.is('textarea') ) { element.focus(); }
});
```

It works fine for already existing elemnt, but not working for the Injected element.

Comment: Can you add your code so we can see if there is an error in it?

Comment: **Do I need to delegate to get offset?** yes. but need to see the code.

Comment: you delegate event binding... can't answer using delegate for this case without seeing code that is causing problem